How do we know which particle to use for がっかりする？
I'm confused over when to use which particle for the word, がっかりする, as well as other verbs that may use a range of different particles in different contexts. Is there a specific rule to knowing when to use which particle?
I've found several sentences using がっかりする on jisho.com. Here are the examples:
息子にがっかりした。
I was disappointed in my son.
評判の小説だったので期待して読んだが、薄っぺらい内容でがっかりした。
I had high expectations of the novel because of its reputation, but I was disappointed by its frivolous content.
Why were different particles used in these sentences?
(Also shoutout to @naruto and others for always helping out with confusions over grammar! いつもありがとうございます。)

In English we can say, in your own words, "disappointed in", "disappointed by", "disappointed with".  Perhaps in the Japanese there are differences with the use of different particles, but I would be hard pressed to explain the differences with the different prepositions in English.

@A.Ellett Actually, that sounds like an excellent question for english.SE and/or ell.SE (depending on how it's posed), if it doesn't exist already.

～でがっかりする and ～にがっかりする are both correct.

薄っぺらい内容にがっかりした。
I was disappointed by the frivolous content.
薄っぺらい内容でがっかりした。
(it had) frivolous content, and (so) I was disappointed.

In this case, there isn't much difference between the two. Grammatically, に is this particle に to mark the cause of a psychological reaction. This で is not a particle but the te-form of だ to connect two independent clauses, implying a cause-effect relationship (essentially the same as 薄っぺらい内容だったのでがっかりした).
However, the difference between に and で would be huge in your first example:

息子にがっかりした。
(My son did something nasty and) I was disappointed by my son.
息子でがっかりした。
(I was expecting a baby girl, but) It was a son, so I was disappointed.
(I was expecting someone else to come, but) It was my son, so I was disappointed.

